# Why does matplotlib's Slider only allow a range of 0-7?

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib, bit-manipulation

I am trying to plot the values of a bitwise circular shift on 1 byte. I'd like to have a slider let me change the original input value. I'm using the slider example on the matplotlib site for reference, but for some reason even though I pass in 0-255 as my slider range when I run my script the range is always 0-7. I'm guessing that somehow the slider is getting locked to my maximum number of x values, but I don't see how. How do I get the slider to let me pick the full 0-255 range?

Also, despite the min/max I've given the slider it inserts some padding for going below 0 at the front, and randomly draws a verticle line in the middle of my slider. How do I get rid of it? (also what is it for? The purpose isn't obvious to me)

Picture of slider only going up to 7:
[image]

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

from numpy import uint8
from numpy import uint16
from numpy import uint32
from numpy import uint64

def sizeof(x):
    return [uint8, uint16, uint32, uint64].index(x) + 1

def rot(x, i):
    return type(x)((x >> i) | (x << (sizeof(type(x))*8 - i))) 

def plotShifts(x):
    origType = type(x)
    maxval = type(x)(-1)

    numrots = sizeof(type(x)) * 8
    vals = [rot(x, i) for i in range(numrots)]

    print vals

    l, = plt.plot(range(numrots), vals, 'ro')

    axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
    inputax = plt.axes([0.15, 0.05, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axcolor)
    inputsl = Slider(inputax, 'Input', 0, maxval, valinit=0, valfmt="%d")

    def update(x):
        vals = [rot(origType(x), i) for i in range(numrots)]
        l.set_ydata(vals)
        plt.draw()
    inputsl.on_changed(update)

    plt.axis([-0.5, numrots-1 + 0.5, -2, maxval + 2])

plotShifts(uint8(1))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the last line `plt.axis([-0.5, numrots-1 + 0.5, -2, maxval + 2])` which is acting on the axes that holds the slider, not on the axis with the data.

I would recommend using the OO interface to `matplotlib` rather than the `pyplot` interface for anything programmatic.  The `pyplot` interface is good for interactive stuff, but it has a good deal of hidden state.

You also need to return a reference to the `slider` object due to the way call backs work.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

from numpy import uint8
from numpy import uint16
from numpy import uint32
from numpy import uint64

def sizeof(x):
    return 2 ** [uint8, uint16, uint32, uint64].index(x)

def rot(x, i):
    return type(x)((x >> i) | (x << (sizeof(type(x))*8 - i))) 

def plotShifts(x):
    fig = plt.figure() # make a new figure
    ax = fig.add_axes([0.15, 0.2, 0.65, 0.7]) # add data axes
    origType = type(x)
    maxval = type(x)(-1)

    numrots = sizeof(type(x)) * 8
    vals = [rot(x, type(x)(i)) for i in range(numrots)]

    print vals
    print maxval
    l, = ax.plot(range(numrots), vals, 'ro') # plot to data axes

    axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
    inputax = fig.add_axes([0.15, 0.05, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axcolor)
    inputsl = Slider(inputax, 'Input', 0, maxval, valinit=0, valfmt="%d")

    def update(x):
        vals = [rot(origType(x), origType(i)) for i in range(numrots)]
        l.set_ydata(vals)
        plt.draw()
    inputsl.on_changed(update)

    ax.set_ylim([-2,maxval +2]) # set ylim on data axes
    ax.set_xlim([-.5,numrots-1+.05]) # set xlim on data axes


    return inputsl

sldr = plotShifts(uint8(1))
plt.show()
```

Comment: doh! Totally forgot about how I was mixing the OOP and state machine interfaces.

Comment: I know I can call axes to make an axes object, since I do that for the slider, but how do I attach it the plot? I've tried a few variations now, calling set_axes on the plot object or passing it in as the axes keyword to the constructor and they all make my plot disappear...

Answer (score 1):

most likely because maxval =7 in this line

```
inputsl = Slider(inputax, 'Input', 0, maxval, valinit=0, valfmt="%d")
```

Comment: Yeah it's 255 because when you assign -1 to an unsigned number you get the highest unsigned number, which for a uint8 is 255.