# On handling the layout of subfigures

Tags: python, matplotlib

I just read an introduction to `subplot2grid` http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html

I don't understand why it is used like

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.subplot2grid((2,2),(0, 0))
```

rather than

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.subplot2grid((2,2),(0, 0))
```

By `plt.subplot2grid(...)`, if I have created multiple figures, which figure the subplot is on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.*` functions act on the **current** figure. To get the current figure you can do

```
fig = plt.gcf()
```

So, in your second case you can do:

```
# Add subplots to the current figure
plt.subplot2grid((2, 2), (0, 0))

# Get the current figure. This will hold the subplots created in the previous command
fig = plt.gcf()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So if I want to do it on a particular figure, I need to set it as the current figure first?

Comment: Exactly. To keep track of your figures, you can assign them numbers like so: `fig1 = plt.figure(1)` or `fig2 = plt.figure(2)`. You can then switch the current figure back to `fig1` like so: `plt.figure(1)`. Hope that helps.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986567/matplotlib-how-to-set-the-current-figure) explains it better.

Answer (score 1):

There are two model for interacting with `matplotlib`, the [state machine interface](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html) (plt.*) and the [OOP](http://matplotlib.org/api/index.html) model (acting on `figure` or `axes`, etc).  The state machine interface imitates matlab and is very useful for interactive sessions to quickly, however if you are going to do anything problematically it is much better to use the OOP interface.  Mixing the two can lead [to problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980919/why-does-matplotlibs-slider-only-allow-a-range-of-0-7/12981340#12981340).

Comment: You leave it completely unclear how you would use `subplot2grid` in OOP model, since `Figure` has no `subplot2grid` attribute. Therefore this answer is not at all helpful.

Comment: Indeed. I'm searching for the OOP version of subplot2grid. Does anyone knoes it? I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256144/matplotlib-what-is-the-oop-equivalent-of-gridspec-or-plt-subplot2grid, but it is also not calling fig methods.