# Matplotlib: What is the OOP equivalent of Gridspec or plt.subplot2grid

Tags: matplotlib

To arrange subplots in tables that can have colspans and rowspans the Pyplot-API of Matplotlib uses:

- http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html

In this question user *tcaswell* says that one shouldn't mix the two API's:

- [On handling the layout of subfigures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13098574/on-handling-the-layout-of-subfigures)

Taking this advice in account, how is it possible to do colspans and rowspans without using the Pyplot-API?

### Edit 1

I think it might be good to expand the question with a working example. I implement what user *Julien* recommended in his answer and everything works:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from gi.repository import Gtk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtk3cairo import (FigureCanvasGTK3Cairo
    as FigureCanvas)
from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtk3 import (NavigationToolbar2GTK3 
    as NavigationToolbar)
import mplstereonet
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.set_size_request(500, 500)
        self.box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=6)
        self.add(self.box)

        self.fig = Figure(dpi = 80)
        gridspec = GridSpec(3, 3)

        subplot_one = gridspec.new_subplotspec((0, 0),
                                            rowspan = 1, colspan = 3)
        subplot_two = gridspec.new_subplotspec((1, 0), rowspan = 2,
                                            colspan = 1)
        subplot_three = gridspec.new_subplotspec((1, 1), rowspan = 2,
                                            colspan = 2)

        ax_one = self.fig.add_subplot(subplot_one)
        ax_two = self.fig.add_subplot(subplot_two)
        ax_three = self.fig.add_subplot(subplot_three)

        xdata = [0.5, 0.2, 0.7, 0.3]
        ydata = [0.2, 0.8, 0.2, 0.4]

        ax_one.scatter(xdata, ydata)
        ax_two.scatter(xdata, ydata)
        ax_three.scatter(xdata, ydata)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        self.box.pack_start(self.canvas, True, True, 0)

win = MyWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: User tcaswell is in fact the author of matplotlib...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the answer lies in the `pyplot.subplot2grid` documentation:

http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot2grid

Assuming you have defined a figure `fig`

```
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
gridspec = GridSpec(nrows, ncols)
subplotspec = gridspec.new_subplotspec((row, col), rowspan, colspan)
ax = fig.add_subplot(subplotspec)
```

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. It has certainly brought me a step farther. Do you maybe know how to add an axis and a plot to your example?

Comment: How about `ax = fig.add_subplot(subplotspec)` and then `ax.plot()`?

Comment: Thanks. I misunderstood where the axis are returned. You made my day!